# Need to add incremental date in excel worksheet in every X number of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am using Excel 2010. I need to find a way to enter a date in a specific cell and have it automatically increment by day and populate that date every 50th cell.

For example:
 
Cell A0001 =  11/19/2017
...
Cell A0050 = 11/20/2017
...
Cell A0100 = 11/21/2017
...
Cell A0550 = 12/01/2017
...
Cell A1600 = 1/1/2018

I have watched a dozen videos on how to increment dates every which way but none of them talk about how to do this AND skip cells.
Is this even possible?

Comment: Have vba enter the dates as appropriate, otherwise an if() with checking the row number could work but that would be in every cell...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first date is in row 1 and you want dates every 50 rows, then the next date will be in row 51, 101, etc. With that in mind, put a date into cell A1. Then use this formula in cell A2 and copy down as far as desired.

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),50)=1,OFFSET(B2,-50,-1)+1,"")
```

Format column A as date. If your data does not start in row 1, adjust the comparison value in the condition of the IF statement. Mod(Row(),50) will return 1 in rows 1, 51, 101, and it will return 2 in rows 2, 52, 102, etc.

Edit: if cells between the formulas need to be blank or have static text, enter the date in the first row, for example E1. You need a real date in cell E1, not a formula, because the formula increments a real date without a starting date there is nothing to increment. Fill the rest of the cells between E1 and E50 with the static text you need. Then put the formula into cell E51 and if it shows the correct date, select cells E2 to E51 and drag down the **fill handle**. That will repeat the pattern of the selected 50 rows in the next  rows.

Comment: So your code works by putting a date in every 50th cell. Thank you for that. The problem is that using the fill bar to drag down also wipes out all the other entries. That's what I meant by skipping cells. Is there a way to jump over cells 2 through 50 and just put the dates into every 50th cell?

Comment: You'd need VBA to apply a formula to only ***some*** cells. If the contents between the two dates is identical every 50 rows, then you could put the correct content into the first 50 cells in column A, then select A1 to A50 and use the fill handle to drag down. With that technique, the pattern of the first 50 cells will be repeated.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me again. 
Instead of trying to "jump" data in certain cells, I am just going to use your function in a new, blank column and then move it into place.<br/>


I have the new column formatted as DATE and I have your function in E1.
After dragging the fill bar down, I get 1/1/1900 in every 50th cell and #REF! in cell E1.<br/>


Obviously I am doing something wrong. Where would I enter my first date?<br/>

Example:
E1   = your function<br/>
E2   = today's date (manually entered)<br/>
E52 = tomorrow's date (calculated by Excel)<br/>

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please do the right thing and mark it as the answer as explained in the [tour].